# Removing Leading Space in Baskervville font

Tags: fonts, symbols

I am using Baskervville-Regular font (https://github.com/anrt-type/ANRT-Baskervville).
I am trying to use `\acute` in text area, but leading was changed when `\acute` symbol presented in the line. See MWE is below

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Baskervville-Regular.ttf}


\begin{document}

WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops{\color{red}{\ensuremath{\acute{\text{A}}}}} and  conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are,loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some{\color{red}{\ensuremath{\acute{\text{b}}}}} time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't type `Á` directly?

Comment: @Sigur is right. This font has accented glyphs with the size and angle of the accents carefully drawn to avoid problems with leading. You defeat the designer’s efforts by using `\ensuremath{\acute{...}}`.

Comment: @Sigur,  I am trying type Á directly, but leading issue not be solve.

Comment: Should there be spaces after "loops" and "some"? Is that the issue? Just put spaces after them.

Comment: Yes, as said by @frabjous, use `some \textcolor{red}{Á} time`.

Comment: TeX’s default leading is inadequate for this typeface; I’d use at least `\linespread{1.0345}`.

Comment: even for fonts that don't have pre-built glyphs like Á  never use the math `\acute` command for a text accent, use `\'{A}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely use *text* accents, not math accents.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Baskervville}[
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
]

\linespread{1.1}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\'}{TU}{b}{\accent"B4 b}

\begin{document}

Á \'A \'b ć \'c

WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose 
for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, 
it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops \textcolor{red}{\'{A}} 
and conditional statements with macro functions rather than  keywords. 
Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, 
loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. 
Sophisticated macro scripts involving admittedly, hard to write and read, 
and it may take some \textcolor{red}{\'{b}} time to become familiar with it. 
However, WinEdt comes with almost  500 predefined macro functions that can 
be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a 
macro language guru to create an interface

\end{document}
```

The accent on `b` would be placed wrongly (because the anchors for composite characters are not well defined for it). The common accented letters are available as precomposed, but you need not know how to input them. In any case `Á` and `\'A` will produce the exact same result.

As per Thérèse comment, I set a larger interline spacing with `\linespread{1.1}`.

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain how to set in math mode also.

Comment: @murugananbu If you want an acute accent over a letter in math mode, then use `\acute`. I’m not sure I understand what you’re asking, though.